# Set Cookies in SOAP header

Tags: http, cookies, soap

I have a requirement where i need to invoke a SOAP  Webservice  operation for login and get the cookie from the  SOAP response and use  the cookie  to invoke another SOAP operation to retrieve some data.  The Login operation response has a cookie(**Set-Cookie**) which looks like **ASP.NET_SessionId=vqjucdxcxrgg5swr0f3z0peb; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax**

Now how do i map this cookie to the retrieve operation. Do i map **ASP.NET_SessionId=vqjucdxcxrgg5swr0f3z0peb; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax** fully or just **ASP.NET_SessionId=vqjucdxcxrgg5swr0f3z0peb** or just **vqjucdxcxrgg5swr0f3z0peb**. I tried all three options and i am getting **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Port may not be negative error** when i invoke the retrieve operation. Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong. I am using Tibco BW to invoke the SOAP operations.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question in the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie .Please read below

Setting a cookie
Cookies are set using the Set-Cookie HTTP header, sent in an HTTP response from the web server. This header instructs the web browser to store the cookie and send it back in future requests to the server (the browser will ignore this header if it does not support cookies or has disabled cookies).

As an example, the browser sends its first request for the homepage of the www.example.org website:

GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
...
The server responds with two Set-Cookie headers:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: theme=light
Set-Cookie: sessionToken=abc123; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT
```

...
The server's HTTP response contains the contents of the website's homepage. But it also instructs the browser to set two cookies. The first, "theme", is considered to be a session cookie since it does not have an Expires or Max-Age attribute. Session cookies are intended to be deleted by the browser when the browser closes. The second, "sessionToken", is considered to be a persistent cookie since it contains an Expires attribute, which instructs the browser to delete the cookie at a specific date and time.

Next, the browser sends another request to visit the spec.html page on the website. This request contains a Cookie HTTP header, which contains the two cookies that the server instructed the browser to set:

```
GET /spec.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Cookie: theme=light; sessionToken=abc123
```

…
This way, the server knows that this request is related to the previous one. The server would answer by sending the requested page, possibly including more Set-Cookie headers in the response in order to add new cookies, modify existing cookies, or delete cookies.

The value of a cookie can be modified by the server by including a Set-Cookie header in response to a page request. The browser then replaces the old value with the new value.

Cookie attributes

In addition to a name and value, cookies can also have one or more attributes. Browsers do not include cookie attributes in requests to the server—they only send the cookie's name and value. Cookie attributes are used by browsers to determine when to delete a cookie, block a cookie or whether to send a cookie to the server.